# breakpoints not working after installing valgrind

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, breakpoints, valgrind

I just installed valgrind but now my breakpoints dont work in qtcreator.  How can I fix this?

debug:NO GDB PROCESS RUNNING, CMD IGNORED: -stack-list-arguments 2 0 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with QTcreator itself and not Valgrind this was a coincidence that I had added all the possible views for debugger (Debug->Views  then select them all)  this somehow made most of my code unreachable by breakpoints.  Is this a bug or a consequence of the type of views I added?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you give us more information, it's hard to believe that simply *installing* valgrind has broken gdb.

If you are trying to run the debugger *from* valgrind, what options are you using for `--db-attach` and `--db-command`?

Comment: after uninstalling valgrind and restoring the debugger views to default in creator I also had to clean the whole project and run qmake once more to get breakpoints to work again. Sounds pretty odd but I definitely got that problem after installing valgrind and playing with the views.